# Stored Proc works in VS 2010 development Server and not in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, stored-procedures

Dear All,
I have a tremendous problem. I am developing an ASP.Net web site for a coursework in my university. I have completed the site and I used procs for each and every interaction with the DB (MS SQL Server 2008). Having finished the site, I tried to deploy the Site in the IIS 7 web server of the university because I will need to create Web services and also create  Silvelight projects …
The thing is that the procs do not retrieve data after deployment in IIS. In VS2010 the project works perfectly. The conn string is ok. I can retrieve data (having deployed to IIS). if I use

comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
and provide the command string. But not if I use Stored procs. 
e.g.

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ai932.Proc_RetrieveDocs", conn);
comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
adapter.Fill(dTable);

ALTER PROCEDURE [ai932].[Proc_RetrieveDocs] 
AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * from ai932.Doctor;
```

END

I cannot understand where is the problem? Please some help !!!

Comment: check execute permissions of the user in the connection string, might not have it; do you get any errors?

Comment: Does your connection string use Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication?

Comment: i take a "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object ‘Proc_InsertDoc’, database’ai932’,
schema ‘ai932’. "

Answer (score 0):

What user does the IIS App Pool service run as? Is it NETWORK SERVICE? Does NETWORK SERVICE have permission to run the stored procedure?

Comment: I do not have access to the IIS. Even for changing my folder directories to application folders, I contact the support team to do it. Not to mention that the technician that I contact today said that my procedure does not return anything :), and that it is the reason that it does not work.